# Modify the videoBuffer to stream to RTSP from DJI drone

Tags: android, ffmpeg, rtsp, dji-sdk

I need to stream the `videoBuffer` from the camera callback to a RTSP server.

```
// The callback for receiving the raw H264 video data for camera live view
    mReceivedVideoDataCallBack = new DJICamera.CameraReceivedVideoDataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(byte[] videoBuffer, int size) {
            // Send the raw H264 video data to RTSP server here
        }
    };
```

I also tried dumping the `byte[] videoBuffer` to a file on Android and tried to playback. It won't play. I guess it has something to do with the encoding of the `videoBuffer`.

Can someone explain how I can

1. Dump the `videoBuffer` to a file, and make it playable?
2. Modify the `videoBuffer` to be able to stream that over RTSP?

I have added the FFMPEG library for Android for RTSP streaming but I believe it does not accept `byte[] buffer` as input.

**Setup:** DJI Phantom 4 Pro with Android SDK.

Things above need to be implemented on Android.

Comment: which version of sdk are you using? please update to latest version and use provideTranscodedVideoFeed() method in VideoFeeder to get the standard h264 stream

Comment: Hi, I'm using sdk version 4.8. As per your comment, I found this `VideoFeeder.VideoFeed provideTranscodedVideoFeed()`, Can you please share an example how to use this?

Comment: related interfaces will be available soon.

Comment: did anyone got the answer ?